# Convert Map to Record in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a use case in which I am creating a metric using Math Expression-

```
new MathExpression({
  expression: `SUM([${Object.keys(metricArguments).join(", ")}])`,
  usingMetrics: metricArguments,
})
```

Here metricArguments is a `Map<string,IMetric>` but `usingMetrics` need `Record<string,IMetric>` type.I wanted to ask how can I convert a `Map<string,Imetric>` into `Record<string,Imetric>` as I have my metrics stored in map.
I could also have inserted the metric in a Record type instead of map but could not find any method to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need a function to convert the `Map` into an object literal.

```
function convertMapToObject(metricArguments: Map<string,IMetric>): Record<string,IMetric> {
  let newObject: Record<string,IMetric> = {}
  for (let [key, value] of metricArguments) {
    newObject[key] = value;
  }
  return newObject;
}

new MathExpression({
  expression: `SUM([${Object.keys(metricArguments).join(", ")}])`,
  usingMetrics: convertMapToObject(metricArguments),
})
```

Comment: Thanks I did not knew how to assign to record.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.fromEntries(map)` to convert the `Map` into an object literal compatible to `Record`, (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

In your use case something like this:

```
new MathExpression({
  expression: `SUM([${Object.fromEntries(metricArguments).join(", ")}])`,
  usingMetrics: metricArguments,
})
```

Comment: This requires support for [ES2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#10th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2019) FYI